# Allow scp/ssh for www-data user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, users

I am on Amazon EC2 using Ubuntu 10.04.2

My web folder is owned by www-data so I want to be able to log into my server as www-data for ssh and scp.

Thanks!

Adding the line to my /etc/ssh/sshd_config does not seem to work.

```
AllowUsers www-data
```

Answer (score 7):

On Debian, which Ubuntu is based on, the www-data user has /bin/sh as the default shell. To enable SFTP, you can create `/var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys` with you public key in it. The permissions on `/var/www/.ssh` should be 700, and the permissions on the authorized_keys file should be 600. You'll want to add the following to your http configuration to prohibit access to this directory.

```
<Directory /var/www/.ssh>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

You can verify the www-data users settings (home dir, shell, etc) using `getent passwd www-data`.

Make sure your sshd_config has `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`, and you'll probably want to set `PasswordAuthentication no` also.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of insecure. I would suggest you to upload to an intermediate area using another user and run a `cron` job from time to time to move stuff where it belogs and change its permissions accordingly.

If you really insist on logging on as `www-data`, you must use a ssh private key to do that (AFAIK EC2 instances only allow key authentication). You must also check that `www-data` has a valid shell on `/etc/passwd` and a valid home dir.

In the end, you can also try some solutions of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/167040/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-ec2-linux-instance-via-ssh-without-the-key-pair).

Comment: I was planning on using a ssh private key to do that. But if I use cron to copy the files over, wouldn't it be a bit slow because I would have to wait for the cron script to copy it over. Also, I wouldn't be able to upload files.

What I really want is something like FTP for www-data but secure like scp.

Comment: The other solutions I give are feasible, I only don't like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this, without relying on `cron` jobs to do the actual work of placing the files in the documentroot, is to make your "regular" SSH account a member of the `www-data` group

```sh
# add your current user to www-data group
sudo usermod -a -G www-data myusername
# restore standard user/group ownership on your webserver documentroot
sudo chown -R root:www-data /path/to/your/webserver/documentroot
```

This way the `myusername` user will have read/write access to the webserver root directory.

Comment: ⚠ **WARNING** ⚠ `sudo usermod -G` replaces all of your groups. You want `sudo usermod -a -G`. I almost lost `sudo` access on my server.

Answer (score -4):

Logging in as www-data for scp is waste of time.

For the scp command why you dont use `ssh2_scp_send` for transferring files,it is simple and doesn't need you to add-ssh or create a public key for the user www-data

for example

`ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/directory/filename', '/remotedirectory/filename', 0644);`

should work