# Gitolite and Gitlab - How the `www-data` user can checkout?

Tags: git, gitolite

I have just installed Gitolite and Gitlab and I am very happy with it. Everything works fine so far.
I can create repos, push to them, clone them on other clients on the network. Great!

But now I wanted to do some `post-receive` hooks.
I.e. when I push to some repo, this repo should be checked out on the server in the `/var/www/repos` directory.

I did this with [Gitlabs Deploy Hooks and this Endpoint-Script](https://github.com/johnsmclay/githook_endpoint).

The problem is that the scripts are run under the user "`www-data`" which has no access to `gitlab/gitolite`.

How do I change this?
I need to be able to checkout repos with `www-data` user and using `git@server/repo.git` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ssh for his. If you add the *www-data* user to the *gitolite* group your webserver should be able to read the repositories from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sudo in order to execute the script with the appropriate rights (if you can modify the `sudoers` file).

See for illustration "[Deploying Node Apps via Gitolite and post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481197/deploying-node-apps-via-gitolite-and-post-receive-hook/12481490#12481490)".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am getting stuck a litte bit ealier:
My Problem was that the www-data user has no ssh pub/private key-pair that I could enter in gitlab. So gitolite(?) prompts me to enter the password for the user "git"...

Comment: @mblaettermann any chance to generate the ssh keys for that www-data users and storing them in the standard path `~www-data/.ssh`? And publish that public key on GitLab through the GitLab GUI?

Comment: Will try that...!

Comment: [I will try this... Sounds good!](http://serverfault.com/a/260786/135681)